# Bundled Material theme in WebStorm 2019.3 is invalid with current version

Tags: material-design, webstorm

I upgraded to WebStorm 2019.3 a few days ago and now the bundled Material theme shows the error 'Incompatible with the current WebStorm version'. In the Marketplace tab the version of Material theme is 4.10.0 Dez. 01, 2019. As it is bundled I can't de-install it. Any hints how to rid of the error or this theme?

Screenshot of Settings - Plugins:

[image: Screenshot of Settings - Plugins]

Comment: Bundled Material UI Theme plugin? TBH I doubt about this, that JetBrains would bundle any 3rd party plugins. Offer to install -- yes, but bundle -- no. I believe you must have read it wrong somehow; please post some screenshots with what you see there.

Comment: added screenshot

Comment: Has to be some glitch. I've just installed WebStorm 2019.3 and that plugin was offered as a custom install -- it's not bundled for sure. Suggestion to fix -- reinstall plugin. 1) Close IDE 2) Locate plugins folder (see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs) 3) Delete that plugin file manually 4) Launch IDE and see how it behaves (if plugin is listed etc) 5) Install that plugin again via Plugins screen.

Comment: After deleting plugin and reinstalling it works again. The old plugin on the disk was 4.2. instead of the displayed 4.10. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Has to be some glitch as that's a 3rd party plugin and JetBrains will NOT bundle such plugins (but may offer on fresh install). I've just installed trial of WebStorm 2019.3 on Windows and that plugin was offered as a custom install -- it's not bundled for sure.

Solution -- reinstall plugin to fix this issue. For this:

1. Close IDE
2. Locate plugins folder (check https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs to locate plugins folder that is specific for your OS)
3. Manually delete that plugin file (could also be a folder; depends on plugin)
4. Launch IDE and check if plugin is still listed there (should not be listed now)
5. Install Material Theme UI plugin again using Plugins screen

Comment: After deleting the folder, and reopening the IDE, Material Theme Plugins still appears listed, so i had to "uninstall" the plugin from the IDE first, before restarting the IDE. This will make possible to reinstall the plugin and get it working.